# cmd line work in cmd and error 53 in batch file

Tags: command-line, batch-file

i have a cmd line:

```
net use Y: \\SERVER\sharename
```

when i run it from cmd it works, but in the batch file it's not working, error 53 is appearing.

i have the problem only when the folder name is hebrew characters.

PLEASE HELP
THANKS

Comment: Soundsmlike a problem with the encoding of the file (e.g. UTF8 without BOM).

Comment: What is the complete batch file? Have you tried putting the UNC path in quotes?

Comment: I'm with @flolilolilo, this is an encoding issue. Try opening the batch file in Notepad++ and use the encoding menu to change to something appropriate for the language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an encoding issue: CMD cannot read your file. 
To solve: Open the file in Notepad++ and change the encoding using the encoding menu.